# Экранирование символов при отправке формы POST php

Tags: php

У меня в системе есть поле для регулярного выражения и для ввода значения, которое проверяется регулярным выражением

preg_match ($regular_expression,$value)

При отправке с формы $regular_expression символ \ экранириует как \, также начиная с версии PHP 7.3 нужно экранировать знак -

Прошу, если есть, поделиться более универсальным способом экранирования в данном случае.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-quote

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.